# NullPointerException Java JPA CDI Tomcat

Tags: java, jpa, tomcat, nullpointerexception, cdi

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java de teste com JPA, CDI e Tomcat. Criei uma classe básica de teste e estou recebendo o seguinte erro.

```
Erro: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.hcancerbarretos.espec.dao.EspecialidadesDAO.getEspecialidades(EspecialidadesDAO.java:16)
    at br.com.hcancerbarretos.espec.testes.Teste.main(Teste.java:13)
```

A `EspecialidadeDAO` está nula, não está sendo injetada corretamente com o `@Inject`. O mais estranho é que se eu crio uma página JSF e exibo os valores em um dataTable, tudo que tem `@Inject` é injetado normalmente.
Criei também uma classe de Webservice chamada EspecialidadeWS, onde a injeção de dependência de EspecialidadeDAO não funciona.

Alguém sabe me dizer como corrigir isso? Porque acontece? Alguma saída? Seguem abaixo os arquivos e classes.

Classe modelo:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Especialidade.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Especialidade e")
public class Especialidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ESPECEALIDADE_ID")
    private long especialidadeId;

    private String descricao;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="DT_ALT")
    private Date dtAlt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="DT_INCL")
    private Date dtIncl;

    private String sigla;

    @Column(name="USU_ALT")
    private String usuAlt;

    @Column(name="USU_INCL")
    private String usuIncl;

    public Especialidade() {
    }

    //getters and setters ...
}
```

Código da classe EspecialidadeDAO.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import br.com.hcancerbarretos.espec.model.Especialidade;

public class EspecialidadesDAO {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<Especialidade> getEspecialidades() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Especialidade.findAll", Especialidade.class).getResultList();
    }

    public String getEspecialidadePorCodigo(long codigo) {
        return em.createQuery("select e.descricao From Especialidade e Where e.especialidadeId = :codigo", String.class)
                .setParameter("codigo", codigo).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Classe `EntityManagerProducer`:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {

    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public EntityManagerProducer() {
        this.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Especialidade");
    }

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        manager.close();
    }

}
```

Classe teste:

```
import java.util.List;
import br.com.hcancerbarretos.espec.dao.EspecialidadesDAO;
import br.com.hcancerbarretos.espec.model.Especialidade;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        EspecialidadesDAO dao = new EspecialidadesDAO();
        List<Especialidade> especialidades = dao.getEspecialidades();        
    }
}
```

Classe EspecialidadeWS.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import br.com.hcancerbarretos.espec.dao.EspecialidadesDAO;

public class EspecialidadeWS {

    @Inject
    private EspecialidadesDAO dao;

    public String getEspecialidade(long codigo){
        System.out.println("DAO " + dao);
        return dao.getEspecialidadePorCodigo(codigo);
    }   
}
```

Arquivo `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Especialidade</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

</web-app>
```

Arquivo `META-INF\context.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- disables storage of sessions across restarts -->
    <Manager pathname="" />
    <Resource name="BeanManager" auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager" factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

O arquivo `beans.xml` está criado, porém vazio, como recomendado.

Comment: Se a exceção está ocorrendo na linha 16 da EspecialidadesDAO, então ele deve ter sido, sim, injetada, e o erro pode estar nela. Poderia colar também o código de EspecialidadesDAO?

Comment: Debugando a aplicação eu verifico que a EntityManager não foi injetada.
Coloquei o código da classe logo abaixo Victor.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se você está tentando usar no método main não vai dar certo!

Porque: Você tá usando um recurso chamado [CDI](http://blog.caelum.com.br/use-cdi-no-seu-proximo-projeto-java/), que é basicamente um módulo rodando no teu container de aplicação que sempre que uma instância anotada com @EJB ou @Inject é usada ele intercepta a thread e passa uma instância que ele mesmo cria, ou reaproveita. Basicamente falando, rodando no tomcat é ele que faz um "new Object()" no entityManager dentro de EspecialidadeDAO pra você.

Rodando no main você vai ter que criar a instância do EntityManager usando [EntityManagerFactory](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html) e passar ela pra dentro do teu EspecialidadesDAO, justamente porque não tem esse robozinho fazendo o serviço por você.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Cleiton.
O que eu acho estranho é o seguinte, com a página JSF funciona porque o Tomcat está no ar, porém se eu tenho uma classe Webservice que lá dentro injeto a EspecialidadeDAO com @Inject por exemplo, isso também não funciona, mesmo com o Tomcat no ar.
Teoricamente se o problema do CDI não funcionar é o container não estar no ar, neste caso que eu citei deveria funcionar não é?
De início eu achei que o CDI só funcionava com servidores de aplicação Java EE (Wildfly, Glassfish), porém depois vi que também funciona com servlet container como o Tomcat.

Comment: @Reginaldo, se tu tá tentando executar pelo método main, não vai funcionar, independente de o server estar up ou não é outra jvm rodando.

Comment: @CleitonCardoso eu não entendi muito bem porque isso não funciona na classe de Teste. 
E outra dúvida, em relação a classe de Webservice EspecialidadeWS eu também não consegui funcionar, sabe me dizer porque e me ajudar com alguma dica? Atualmente a injeção de dependência está funcionando somente em views com JSF.
Obrigado.

Comment: @Reginaldo, atualizei a resposta, dá uma olhada.

Comment: @CleitonCardoso muito obrigado pela resposta, entendi certinho porque não funciona no main. Só que pensando na classe de Webservice (EspecialidadeWS), ele é gerenciado pelo Axis no meu caso. Quando uma requisição é feita para este webservice, o Tomcat não consegue utilizar o CDI pra criar estas instâncias como no JSF por exemplo?
Obrigado.

Comment: Teu projeto tá em algum repo público? Se não, consegue colocar? Assim fica mais fácil de alguém baixar e testar pra ver o que tá acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Anote sua classe `EspecialidadeWS` com `@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` para funcionar como *web service.*

**EDIT:**

Nos meus projetos utilizo o **RESTEasy** em conjunto com o **CDI** para fazer funcionar a injeção que você deseja. Vamos lá: também é necessário criar, no seu projeto, uma classe que estende a `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`:

```
package abc;

import abc.EspecialidadeWS;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class AppRs extends Application {

    private Set<Class<?>> classes;

    public AppRs() {
        classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(EspecialidadeWS.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }
}
```

No `web.xml`:

```
<!--  RESTEasy  -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>br.com.t2tecnologia.AppRs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.injector.factory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory</param-value>
</context-param>
```

No `pom.xml` (maven):

```
<!--  CDI (esse você já deve ter)  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<!--  RESTEasy  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Classe `EspecialidadeWS`:

```
@Path("/especialidade")
@GET
public class EspecialidadeWS {

    @Inject private EspecialidadesDAO dao;

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{codigo}")
    public String getEspecialidade(@PathParam("codigo") long codigo){
        return dao.getEspecialidadePorCodigo(codigo);
    }   
}
```

Por fim, anote `EspecialidadeWS` também com `@javax.ws.rs.Path("/especialidade")`. Se tudo funcionar, você deverá conseguir acessar seu *web service* via http://localhost:8080/seu_projeto/rest/especialidade/get/1, por exemplo.

Comment: Victor, anotei a classe EspecialidadeWS com @javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped e não funcionou.
Anotei também a classe EspecialidadeDAO apenas para teste, mas também não funcionou.

Comment: No seu projeto, você criou uma classe que estende a `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`?

Comment: Não criei não, desculpe a ignorância, mas para o que serve?
Eu criei essa classe Webservice e fui pelo wizard do Eclipse (Ctrl+N > Web service) para gerar o web service com o Axis.

Comment: Acontece que o `JSF` faz a injeção de dependência pra você. Porém, quando chamamos um web service, estamos num lugar "sem dono", onde você precisa do RESTEasy ou similar para tratar as chamadas de web service. Prefiro o RESTEasy pois ele realmente é fácil e usar e possui integração com CDI, além de converter entidades em JSON/XML e vice-versa automaticamente.

Comment: Neste caso eu preciso que seja SOAP mesmo, devido a comunicação que devo fazer com um outro webservice, de uma empresa terceira, que é SOAP.

Comment: Já trabalhei em um projeto com RESTEasy e Wildfly, mas neste caso eu preciso que seja SOAP mesmo, devido ao padrão de um outro webservice que vou ter que comunicar.
Em WS SOAP com Wildlfy eu fazia anotando a classe como Webservice e Webmethod para os métodos, mas isso utilizando o Wildfly. No caso com o Tomcat, eu tive que realizar a geração do webservice através do wizard do Eclipse, pelo menos foi o que eu fiz e funcionou, porém sem utilizar CDI. Nesse caso para eu criar o WS SOAP com CDI e Tomcat, o que mais eu teria que fazer? Obrigado.

Comment: Com estas configurações que te passei, também funcionaria no Tomcat 7 ou 8. Com o Axis, acredito que não seja possível fazer funcionar com CDI, mas não tenho certeza... Vai ficar a cargo de uma boa pesquisa. Boa sorte!

Comment: Entendi, pode ser que o problema neste caso seja o Axis então. Você já chegou a trabalhar com Webservice SOAP utilizando Tomcat ou Wildfly com CXF?

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com o CXF. Tenho projetos web services SOAP no GlassFish 3, e com web services REST no Tomcat 7/8 e WildFly 8.2+ (estes utilizando JSF, JPA, CDI (Weld) e RESTEasy).

Comment: Tranquilo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

tente isso

```
public class EspecialidadeWS {

    @Inject
    private EspecialidadesDAO dao;

    public String getEspecialidade(long codigo){
        try{
            String codigo = dao.getEspecialidadePorCodigo(codigo);
            return codigo;
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return ''
        }
    }   
}
```

Você não está tratando o código no caso da especialidade não existir.
Outra coisa que pude observar é que o atributo "descrição" e outros não está mapeado na sua entidade. Mapeie...

```
@Column(name="ESPECEALIDADE_ID")
private String descricao;
```